# Decipher of Hex-String with aes-128-cbc and IV

Tags: node.js, cryptography, hex

I am using the following code, trying to decipher a hex-message "EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88" with a hex-key of "00000000000000000000000000000000" and the same for the iv-hex of "00000000000000000000000000000000".

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function decrypt(messageHex, keyHex, ivHex) {
    const key = Buffer.from(keyHex, 'hex');
    const iv = Buffer.from(ivHex, 'hex');

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(messageHex, 'hex');
    decrypted += decipher.final();
    return decrypted;
}

const decryptedCipherText = decrypt(
    'EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000',
);

console.log('Decoded Ciphertext: ' + decryptedCipherText);
```

i am given this error:

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:170
  const ret = this[kHandle].final();
                            ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
    at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:170:29)
    at decrypt (/Users/manuelmertl/workspace/coaaas/ntag/index3.js:9:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/manuelmertl/workspace/coaaas/ntag/index3.js:13:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  function: 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex',
  reason: 'bad decrypt',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_BAD_DECRYPT'
}
```

though i am expecting this return value from the decrypt function:

```
C704DE5F1EACC0403D0000DA5CF60941
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you :)

Comment: The padding must be disabled: `decipher.setAutoPadding(false);`. Furthermore, the output-encoding of `update` (3rd parameter) and `final` (1st parameter) must be set to `hex`.

Comment: Thank you, @Topaco - it works that way. I will post my updated code above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

solution based on @Topaco feedback from the comment:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function decrypt(message, keyHex, ivHex) {
    const key = Buffer.from(keyHex, 'hex');
    const iv = Buffer.from(ivHex, 'hex');

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(message, 'hex', 'hex');
    decrypted += decipher.final('hex');
    return decrypted;
}

var decryptedCipherText = decrypt(
    'EF963FF7828658A599F3041510671E88',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000',
    '00000000000000000000000000000000',
);

console.log('Decoded Ciphertext: ' + decryptedCipherText);
```